# keep two blogs under the same domain

Tags: import, blogger

I am thinking about starting a self hosted wordpress blog. Currently, I own a blogger blog, written in portuguese.

I'd like to have a blog about technology written in english at a domain, like http://example.com, and my old portuguese blog transfered to http://example.com/portugueseblog or something like this.

From what I've gathered, it's possible to import blogger blogs to wordpress. But how do I import it to this specific url, while still being able to write in the main blog?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[Install WordPress as multi-site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network), choose the option **sub-directories**. Your main blog will now under `example.com/`. Create a second sub-site and set its slug to `portugueseblog`. This site will now be accessible under `example.com/portugueseblog`.

Now import the content from the old blogs into the new one.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about using the auto-installer on the cpanel to install wordpress to example.com and then use that to write the main blog. Then use the auto-installer again to example.com/portugueseblog. Do you think this is possible at all?

Comment: Possible, but really not recommended. Avoid auto-installers, they are sometimes hard to keep up to date or put in a strange place.